# 1st admendment autitor

Tags: privacy, first-amendment, youtube

A person came to our location( business)  as a first amendment auditor,during protesting up the street. Began filming how to get into our building and how many people inside. Came on property,but filmed that she was not.
We feared we were being robbed.She filmed staff car plates, VIN and posted person info. One lady freaked out and attacked her. Found out she posted the whole company faces and info on you tube.We asked you tube to remove us. We were told she has a right to post us without permission. One lady is getting death treats,another sexual harassment calls and they are going to another guys house. All in the name of a person called "Furry potato"  and the 1st amendment she is suing 5 companies, and was shot last year. Is there ANY way to have youtube remove these channels ? She has 2 is there anyway to get the faces taken down or removed ?

Comment: Why have you not spoken to police about threats and harassment? YouTube have told you their answer, changing it will require work of a lawyer (we can't tell you what to do, because that's legal advice we can't give).

Comment: What does the first amendment have to do with anything here?  You, she and Youtube are all non-government entities, so the first amendment almost certainly doesn't apply.  She can call herself a "first amendment auditor" all she wants, she can also call herself the emperor of the United States - both have the same status.  None.  Get a lawyer and let them loose on the situation.

Comment: My goal is to figure out how to get it taken down on you tube. She's sick and crazy.I have filed 4 police reports and a restraining order. I am just trying to see what other options and opinions out here. many lawyers are scared because she trans smh this is NOT  the 1st they had in mind.but she does.

Comment: Then get better lawyers - only a bad lawyer would be afraid of being targeted because of the other sides gender situation, because only a bad lawyer would put themselves in a position where their case can be attacked on that basis.  Get better lawyers.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep trying. I appreciate the advice, I really do.

Answer (score 0):

You can flag the content as a violation of [Youtube's "community standards"](https://www.youtube.com/about/policies/#community-guidelines). These are not enforceable legal requirements, but they are conditions that posters must abide by. Crazy claims about the First Amendment are irrelevant. 
YT has the power to remove the content on that basis. However, it appears that they do not agree with your complaint, which might mean that you failed to make the right complaint (many court cases are tossed out because a plaintif "fails to make a claim"). This is basically between you, whatever PR folks that you have that could persuade YT that they are acting irresponsibly, and YT.

News shows commonly broadcast paces of people without permission – this is entirely legal. Likewise cars, buildings, etc. Usually, you can't photograph a VIN without trespassing, so you could notify the police or at least point this out to your attorney, but this doesn't involve Youtube, instead you might sue the photographer.

Comment: Thank you- I appreciate the comment and help. I will keep trying. The sexual comments to my daughter on this whole thing has really made her depressed. It's just frustrating.But, thank you again.